# How to create an algorithm when given the invariant

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-design, loop-invariants

I am given the following invariant:

`Invariant` The greatest $i$ keys of an Array are always in sorted order on the last $i$ indices of the Array.

I am supposed to create a sorting Algortihm using this invariant. But I seem to have understood the concept of an Invariant differently, because with the information I find online, I can't find an idea for starting this problem.
Do I have to create an algorithm that sorts the first $n-1$ elements in the array? Thanks for your help

Comment: How do you understand the concept of “invariant”? An invariant is a property that is supposed to hold for some thing.

Comment: Yes, this is why I don't understand how I'm supposed to create an algorithm where something like that holds true at all times..

Comment: Don’t you understand the concepts of invariants in general, or this invariant in particular?

I’ll invite you to ask about it in chat so that you can hash this out. ☺

Comment: At every step of your algorithm, the invariant should hold.  I think you can use selection sort starting from the end.

Answer (score 1):

Observations:

1. For $i=0$, you don't know anything about the array.
2. For $i=n$, the array is sorted.

So the idea is to go from $i=0$ to $n$ while maintaining the invariant. This is similar to an inductive proof; in fact, you'll get an inductive algorithm.

- Start with the input array and $i=0$; clearly, the invariant is maintained.
- For some $i \geq 0$, assume that the invariant holds. What do you do to ensure the invariant holds for $i+1$?

I'll let you take it from here.